# Why does min value return as zero and max return as a proper value

Tags: arrays, vb.net, max, min

```
Dim Temp(3), Difference As Double
Dim i As Integer
Const UpperBound As Double = 37.5
Const LowerBound As Double = 36
For i = 1 To 3
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the temeperature of the baby.")
    Temp(i) = Console.ReadLine()
    If Temp(i) > UpperBound Or Temp(i) < LowerBound Then
        Console.WriteLine("The temperature is not in the correct range.")
    Else Console.WriteLine("The temperature is within acceptable range.")
    End If
Next
Console.WriteLine("The minimum temperature is " & Temp.Min)
Console.WriteLine("The maximum temperature is " & Temp.Max)
Difference = Temp.Max - Temp.Min
Console.WriteLine("The difference is " & Difference)

Console.ReadKey()
```

Instead of a min value, i get 0 instead

Comment: Welcome to SO. In future, please take time to format your code properly.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are zero indexed, and declared using the **highest addressable index** so when you

```
Dim Temp(3)
```

You're creating an array with **4** slots `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. IMO it's a highly questionable bit of language design.

At the time the array is created, all the slots are initialized with value `0`. Then you put values in indexes `[1, 2, 3]`, but not index `0`.

So the array will always have a value at index `0` of `0`.

You can fix this by first, declaring `Temp` with 3 slots, not 4:

```
Dim Temp(2)
```

then adjusting your loop:

```
For i = 0 To 2
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you can get the lower bound and upper bound of an array with [GetLowerBound()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlowerbound?view=netframework-4.8) and [GetUpperBound()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?view=netframework-4.8).  This will allow your code to work, even when you change the size of the array at a later point in time (instead of hard-coding the upper bound in your loop):

```
For i As Integer = Temp.GetLowerBound(0) To Temp.GetUpperBound(0)
    Debug.Print(i & ": " & Temp(i))
Next
```